# How to set a f:selectItem in a specific option after a p:commandButton action?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a javascript code that clears all the `p:inputText` (after a `p:commandButton` action) of the form. The problem is that the `p:selectOneMenu` still has the `f:selectItem` selected in the option it was selected. **I need to put the values in the first** `f:selectItem` of each `p:selectOneMenu`.

How to I do that? How can I clear the selected values?

The java script code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function limpiarForm()
                {
                    document.getElementById("formularioAltas").reset();
                }
            </script>
```

`formularioAltas` is the form id.

The code of the `p:commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{altasBean.agregarRefaccion()}" oncomplete="limpiarForm()" />
```

And that code does not reset(I dont want to clear the values, I just want to put the first option selected) the values of the `p:selectOneMenu`

Here it is:

```
<h:outputText value="Estado de la refacción" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{altasBean.refaccion.estado}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="..." itemValue="0" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ok" itemValue="Ok" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reparar" itemValue="Reparar" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sospechoso" itemValue="Sospechoso" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

The bean:

```
private RefaccionBean refaccion = null;
/**
 * Get the value of refaccion
 *
 * @return the value of refaccion
 */
public RefaccionBean getRefaccion() {
    return refaccion;
}

/**
 * Set the value of refaccion
 *
 * @param refaccion new value of refaccion
 */
public void setRefaccion(RefaccionBean refaccion) {
    this.refaccion = refaccion;
}

public void agregarRefaccion() {
   I did a lot of things here...
   And after those things i clear the p:inputText with the javascript code
   -> After that i want to set the values of the p:selectOneMenu in the fist f:selectItem
}
```

Comment: Do you want to clear values with javascript? Would you mind posting your code so far? :)

Comment: I cleared the p:inputText with javascript. But i want to know how to set the p:selectOneMenu in the first f:selectItem. I just want to know hot to do it, no matters if is javascript or something else. A pure JSF should be better.

Comment: Okay, let me see what I can do

Comment: I'd just clear whatever I wanted in the action method and update the affected components using the update attribute in the commandButton. If you post your xhtml and bean code, I can show you how to do that.

Comment: sure let me put a part of the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josef's answer does lead you in the right direction, but since you shared some code, I will just use it in my answer.

First, make sure that your button calls your bean method and updates the selectOneMenu component after it's done. Although there's some ajax going on here, primefaces abstracts that for you.

```
<p:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{altasBean.agregarRefaccion}" update="selectOneMenu" />
```

The update attribute is important as it will look for the component whose id matches whatever is specified there. So you need to give your selectOneMenu an id. If you need to update more than one component, you can add their ids to the update attribute separated by either space or comma.

```
<h:outputText value="Estado de la refacción" />
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{altasBean.refaccion.estado}" id="selectOneMenu">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="..." itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Ok" itemValue="Ok" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reparar" itemValue="Reparar" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sospechoso" itemValue="Sospechoso" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now it's just a matter of cleaning up your values inside your action method:

```
public void agregarRefaccion() {
   //If you have other values to clean, clean them here
   this.refaccion.estado="0"; //Matches the value for your first item
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. So if I wanted to clear all the form without javascript I had to do the same with all the other components? The update will look like: update="component1 component2 ... componentN" I mean I have a lot of components in the form, Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: When I need to update a lot of components, I just wrap a panel around them (and give it an id) and update the panel; all the children get updated this way. On the bean side you have to clear each value manually, though. But you could list the component ids as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm not entirely sure if I follow you, but let me know if this helps you out at all. It's entirely JSF and I threw in some ajax. You can play around with your javascript still.

Front-end:

```
<p:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.value}" />

<p:commandButton value="button" action="#{bean.action}">
   <f:ajax execute="input" render="output" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:selectOneMenu id="output" value="#{bean.placeValue}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.values}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {

    private String value;
    private List<String> values; 

    @EJB
    private ValueService valueService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        values = valueService.list();
    }

    public void action() {
        // ... Action taken
    }

    public String placeValue() {
        // ... Validation and clear desired values
        return value;
    }


    // ... (getters, setters, etc)
}
```

Comment: What to do if I wanted to clear all the form? How to do it with ajax?

Comment: You could set the values of the variable to `null` or `""` in the `placeValue` method.